# AWGN channel matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

For my current project work, I need to create an AWGN channel in MATLAB. There is a built-in function in MATLAB named 'awgn'. But that returns the value of received signal after passing through awgn channel. I do not need that. I need a function which will return the **channel matrix only**.

E.g. for Rayleigh fading channel matrix one can use this function H= (randn+ 1i*randn)/sqrt(2);

I need something like this for AWGN channel. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch. The AWGN channel is characterized by the output being the input, plus white gaussian noise.

That's all.

The channel matrix is the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Marcus' answer is perfect!
For any wireless channel, y = Hx + n,
where: y = received signal 
       x = transmitted signal
       n = noise in the channel
For an AWGN channel, output 'y' = input 'x' plus 'noise' (AWGN) i.e. y = x + n
Therefore, for AWGN channel, channel matrix or H-matrix is the identity matrix.